# Limit on Character Length $_GET?

Tags: php, get

I have a variable which consists of

```
  // The First Page (hello.php)

 $a = 'goto.php?a_56=63525588000&url=http://www.example.com/site/DISC+cUSTOMc+Studio+24+-               +Windows/1142766.p?
       id=1218224802931&usi=1142766&cmp=RMX&
       ky=2crslw0k9ZOM0ciu2rqi4NsYY7eQnnEyP';

 // The Second Page (goto.php)
 $r = $_GET['url'];

 echo $r; 

//http://www.example.com/site/Disc cCustomc Studio 8 - Windows/1142766.p?id=1218224802931
```

Why is it getting cut off?

Comment: May be it's not URL encoded - use "urlencode" to build query and use urldecode to get data. see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php & http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: although this was not the issue here, be aware that the data you can transmit via the GET method /is/ limited in length (to some kB or so)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a length issue, it's because you want one of your GET parameters (`url` in this case) to contain the `&` character. You need to `urlencode` this character otherwise it will be interpreted as another GET parameter in the request, rather than as part of the `url` parameter.

When urlencoding, `&` will become `%26` and your query string will become this,

```
goto.php?a_56=63525588000&url=http://www.example.com/site/DISC+cUSTOMc+Studio+24+-+Windows/1142766.p?id=1218224802931%26usi=1142766%26cmp=RMX%26ky=2crslw0k9ZOM0ciu2rqi4NsYY7eQnnEyP
```

Comment: OK, I think 3 of these was enough :D

Comment: @Wesley I started writing this before any answer was here :p. That's one of the problems with actually taking your time to answer, by the time you hit submit 3 people have already jumped in with the same answer :( Still.. better to have three identical answers than no answer at all :)

Comment: I always reload when the orange bar of doom descends to make sure I'm actually adding something instead of duplicating. As I'm sure you know, folks are fond of piping in an early half-answer then fine tuning it. Here, have a sympathy vote because we've all been there. Still, this took you 5 minutes to type?

Comment: @Wesley Murch -- Since you gave a sympathy vote out , I will proceed to do the same

Comment: @Wesley, haha, don't think I've ever had a sympathy vote before. Ah the orange bar of doom.. descending from on high and informing you of just how many people can type faster. And no, it didn't take me 5 minutes to type, it was my own fault for writing half an answer, getting distracted by IM (Yes, it seems I have the attention span of a bird attracted to shiny objects), googling what & urlencodes to (which let's be honest, took mere seconds), then writing the next half. So feel free to revoke the sympathy vote since it was of course entirely my own fault ;)

Comment: Just so we're clear on our SO jargon, it's not quite what you'd usually call a sympathy vote. Usually that would mean a vote given to offset a rightfully negative voted post, just because you feel bad for the poster. In that sense, sympathy votes are evil. Downvoting is a responsibility and we all need to make sure we don't allow bad, misleading, rude, and crappy answers to garnish unwarranted upvotes. That being said, goodnight guys. This was entertaining.

Comment: One more thing: @RPM - Don't copy/paste this, make sure you use the php functions provided in the comment and other answers.

Comment: @Wesley Murch -- There is nothing to copy/paste. The only thing that could be potentially copied is my original question. And besides, the problem was fixed in a matter time after I asked this question. Thanks to SO I was able to figure out the answer faster than normal and ultimately succeed with my project.

Answer (score 3):

It's getting cut off because it's treating the `&` in your url parameter as an actual GET parameter divider, when it's not.

You need to use [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to encode your URL.

Answer (score 3):

Because `&` indicates the end of a key/value pair in a query string.

Use [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode) to prepare data for inclusion in a query string.

Comment: This links to a spam site. Be more careful.

Comment: Yikes. Typo, fixed. Not actually a spam site, it didn't link to anything in public DNS. Sounds like your DNS provider operates a spam response for any host name that doesn't have a real site associated with it (or that you bounced through a search engine)

Comment: Yeah I was just wondering about that... It took me to a really bad popup site that didn't want me to go away. Dancing kittys, free ipads, the whole 9. I think I was their one millionth visitor. Ah, I see, it redirected to include `.com`

Answer (score 3):

The ampersand is used to separate parameters in the outside query string. You will need to URL-encode it if you want to use it within a GET parameter.